# getting data from post array using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to post an array that is `name="std_id[]"` from view page.But in controller while trying to print the array using `print_r($std_id)` I can't find any data.  The code is given below..

In view page:

```
<?php
foreach ($all_student as $v_student) {
?>
<tr><td style="display:none"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $v_student->std_id ?>" name="std_id[]"></td>
<td class="center"><?php echo $v_student->std_name; ?></td>
<?php }?>
```

In controller function:

```
$std_id = $this->input->post("std_id[]", true);
print_r($std_id);
exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the input name wrong. You need to change the line

```
$std_id = $this->input->post("std_id[]", true);
```

With:

```
$std_id = $this->input->post("std_id", true);
```